# kubectl rollout status - When the command complete?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Currently I am using this in my pipeline

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml && kubectl rollout status -f deployment.yaml
```

With this in yaml

```
      readinessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 90
        initialDelaySeconds: 120
        periodSeconds: 10
        timeoutSeconds: 10
        failureThreshold: 1
        successThreshold: 1
      livenessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 90
        initialDelaySeconds: 120
        periodSeconds: 20
        timeoutSeconds: 2
        failureThreshold: 1
        successThreshold: 1
```

For me, kubectl rollout is running for a very long time, blocking the deployment pipeline. From [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-status-em-)

> By default 'rollout status' will watch the status of the latest rollout until it's done

My question:

1/ Which actions are the parts that contribute to the deployment "until it's done" (resource creation, resource teardown?... )

2/ Does readinessProbe and livenessProbe contribute to the deployment time

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it? Additionally what do you mean by "kubectl rollout is running for a very long time"? Could you precise this sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The criteria for this are [in the `kubectl` source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/24d21a0/pkg/polymorphichelpers/rollout_status.go#L76-L89).  A deployment is "complete" if:

- It hasn't timed out
- Its updated-replica count is at least its desired-replica count (every new pod has been created)
- Its current-replica count is at most its updated-replica count (every old pod has been destroyed)
- Its available-replica count is at least its updated-replica count (every new pod is running)

You can use `kubectl get deployment -w` or `kubectl get pod -w` to watch a deployment actually happen in real time; the `kubectl get -w` option watches the given resources and prints out a new line whenever they change.  You'll see the following sequence occur (with default Deployment settings, one at a time for "small" deployments):

1. A new pod is created
2. The new pod passes its probes and become ready
3. An old pod is terminated
4. The old pod actually exits and is deleted

So for `kubectl rollout status deployment/...` to finish, all of these steps must happen – new pods are created, new pods all pass their health checks, old pods are destroyed – for every replica in the deployment.

Comment: good explanation. additionally, to answer OPs question regarding readiness and livenessprobes: 
readinessprobes do have an impact on the deployment rollout time. as pods are only considered ready once the readinessprobe has finished successfully. 
livenessprobe however, is to determine whether a pod is still healthy. so usually it does not affect rollout time. howver, if pods become unhealthy before all other pods have been updated a new pod will be created affecting overall deployment time

Comment: I have observed that (4) is not (always?) the case. For me it returns even though a pod is still in the process of being deleted (but hasn't finished as it implements graceful shutdown). But I haven't found information on that behavior. Looking at the code I'm guessing pods that are in the process of deletion are not counted as replicas anymore. Depending on your networking they STILL might get traffic thought, as we observed with AWS EKS

Answer (score 0):

Another reference for this is here in the kubectl source:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/197123726db24c61aa0f78d1f0ba6e91a2ec2f35/pkg/polymorphichelpers/rollout_status.go#L89

It's quite self explanatory if you look at the log messages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34719881)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).